# If $f:X \rightarrow Y$, then is $g(X)=g(f^{-1}(Y))$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, functions

Suppose I have two continuous functions $f,g:X \rightarrow Y$ ($X=Y=\mathbb{R}_+$). Additionally, $f$ is invertible to $f^{-1}:Y \rightarrow X$. Also, $g,f, f^{-1}$ are of smoothness $C^n$. Is $g(X)=g(f^{-1}(Y))$?

---

Attempt: given that $f:X \rightarrow Y$, we can rewrite $g(X)=g(f^{-1}(Y))$ as $g(f^{-1}(f(X))=g(id(X))=g(X)$.

However, it's not clear to me that the derivative of $g(f^{-1}(Y))$, $(g(f^{-1}(Y)))'=g(X)'$ (although I'm not sure that this is necessary). Note that I assume that $f'>0$ so that $f^{-1}{'}$ exists.

Comment: Do you mean "$g(X)=g(f^{-1}(Y))$"?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Fixed!

Comment: Is the last paragraph a separate question?

Comment: On the (possibly mistaken) assumption that the derivatives need to be the same for the functions to be the same, it is related to my main question.

Comment: You are really often mixing the notation. Let $X$ and $Y$ be the sets while $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$. Otherwise, it doesn't make sense what you wrote.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt, I know. Sorry about that! I think I fixed it?

Comment: I still don't get your statement about the derivative. If you are state $(g\circ f^{-1})'=g'$ then it's false.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt it'd be great if you could elaborate why this does not hold in your answer.

Comment: Simply use the chain rule and you get $(g\circ f^{-1})'(y)=g'(f^{-1}(y))(f^{-1})'(y)$. That is in general different from $g'$.

Answer (score 2):

For every function $g,f:X\to Y$ you get $f^{-1}(Y)=X$ in sense of preimages. Therefore $g(X)=g(f^{-1}(Y))$. The functions don't need any assumptions.

But if $f$ is invertible, then you can consider $g\circ f^{-1}:Y\to Y$ as a function, which is well defined.

Comment: $g\circ f^{-1}$ is from $Y$ to $Y$, not $Y$ to $X$.